# 3 cables leading to a three way switch box

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch

My outdoor light is not working (never was, just purchased this townhouse) I asked the neighbors where their switch is for the light and they said it’s in the garage. I saw mine was covered up with a plastic plate, so I opened it and all the independent wire colors were twisted together. I bought a 3 way switch and tried every combination possible and looking online how to wire it. I end up tripping the breaker most of the time or the light just won’t work.. how do I wire this?[image]

Comment: DON'T EVER EXPERIMENT unless you know exactly what you are doing.  A breaker trip is proof positive you do not.   The reason is: if you are groping around randomly, you will find lots of combinations that work *and will kill you*.  Obviously you'll stop at the first one that "works", and so you'll set yourself up a booby trap.

Comment: If your skill/competency level is such that you thought randomly connecting wires together to see if you could make it work was an acceptable course of action, then what you should do is to flip the breaker for the circuit to the off position and hire a licensed electrician to inspect all of the wiring for damage (both here and any other circuits you may have worked on in the past) and correctly install the switch before your burn your home down.

Comment: And online is no help, because things like these are not standardized.  They are custom fit for every installation.  Even wire colors are not standard. Sometimes white is hot!!! 90% of the information about what the wires do, is stored in *how the wires were connected before*.  If you have "before" pictures, they will help *a lot*.

Comment: @Thesystem32  Yes, if you just touch it maybe you'll be fine but energizing an item that you accidentally grab and you won't be able to let go..... that's when you die. I've seen it happen...

Comment: Zero conduits. 3 cables.

Comment: Do you have some way of figuring out if any of the wires are an always-hot?

Comment: @ThreePhasrEel yes I do, there is one back wire that is always hot

Comment: Which black wire is always-hot?

Comment: The one coming out of the far right conduit

Comment: When you say "far right", which side of the box is the "right" side we should be referring to, given the photo you are showing us? Also, these are cables you're looking at, not conduits